# How to Remove Knowledge Article footernote

Tags: force.com, knowledge, servicecloud, articles

I have created one Article and i published successfully after i assigned that article to site using visualforce page. once i clicked that article in site it will be redirected to anther page. but that article having force.com footer note logo. how can i delete force.com footer note logo and footer content in articles top and bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try once... you can remove site template page access in visualforce pages in site profile and site settings. that site template page having force.com header and footer.

Comment: Removed SiteTemplate  access in site. header and footer still showing. when article redirected to another page like above image